# CSS Need tips for Gallery layout

Tags: html, css

Some of the layouts I have been tasked with converting utilize the following layout (see image.) I'm wondering what the best way using CSS is to render a list of images accordingly. I don't want to split up the items into different row containers just to make things fit. I'm sure there's a way to create this a list.

The biggest problem I have is rendering the images with the appropriate margins in-between and having the far right image line up with the edge of the layout container (orange lines.)

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to maintain the html as something like:

```
<ul class="gallery-list">
    <li class="gallery-list-item">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </li>
    <li class="gallery-list-item">
        <img src="..." alt="..." />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your time and if there is a better solution, I'd be happy to close this and link to the solution.

Comment: Should it be responsive? Are the images fixed-sized? Will it always be 4 images per row?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @kodos-johnson Yes responsive. I suppose the desktop view would be 4 per row but would change to lower amounts in smaller windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a solution, it might not. It makes a few assumptions like there always being four images per row but making them responsive.

The main points are:

- We set the image container width a percentage of the parent container to control the number of images per row.
- We use a right negative margin on the `ul` to offset the right margin applied to the `li` for image spacing.
- We use `calc` to subtract the margin we use for spacing so all elements will fit on a single line and not begin to reflow.

I've used a couple media queries to show how you would change row count for smaller screens to make the grid responsive.

There's also a bit of padding and border applied to `.container` to demonstrate that the images are taking up the full width of the container.

This is just one way to do things.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  /* following adding for demo purposes */
  padding: 50px 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  margin-right: -5px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: calc( 50% - 5px );
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; /* or max-width: 100%; */
  height: auto;
}
@media( min-width: 550px ) {
  li {
    width: calc( 33.333% - 5px );
  }
}
@media( min-width: 750px ) {
  li {
    width: calc( 25% - 5px );
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/fc0/&text=1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ccc/&text=2">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/fc0/&text=3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ccc/&text=4">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/fc0/&text=5">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ccc/&text=6">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/fc0/&text=7">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/ccc/&text=8">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! @hungerstar this is exactly what I was looking for! I guess I need to look into `calc()` a little more.

Comment: No problem. As long as you don't need to support IE8 or older you should be good, [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could go about this. I'm partial to flexbox - this example shows it with a fixed width on the gallery, but you can use a fluid one as well. I'd recommend doing some reading about flexbox, but here's a starting place:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 440px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


.gallery img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gallery">
  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="Artwork">
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: You have extra space on the right side of `.gallery` that the OP might want to get ride of.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use display:flex and flex-wrap for this

I have changed markup from ul li's to div and img's and i have let the last image for every row to grow and fit the container

check this snippet

```css
.gallery-list-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
div img:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
div.gallery-list-item img:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}
div.gallery-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-list">
  <div class="gallery-list-item">
    <img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/123/36699123-images.png" alt="..." height=100 width=100/>


    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" alt="..." height=100 width=100/>

    <img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/123/36699123-images.png" alt="..." height=100 width=100/>

    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" alt="..." height=100 width=100/>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-list-item">
    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" alt="..." height=100 width=100/>

    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" alt="..." height=100 width=100/>

    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" alt="..." height=100 width=100/>

    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" alt="..." height=100 width=100/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope it helps